# Table width exceed the div

Tags: html, css

Please check this link: http://jsfiddle.net/LokeshMasih/sdj9kcqk/

Width of Inner div `id="divTable"` exceeding the outer div because of the width of inner's table `(id="tblInner")` headers.

Now I want to apply the scrollbar in Inner div `id="divTable"` for table `id="tblInner"`. And all width should be in percentage(%)

Comment: Thanks @Dyrandz Famador to edit the post.

Comment: see this https://jsfiddle.net/z137yjfs/

Comment: @Kishan: Inner div supposed to be inside of the outer div with fixed width (in %) with scroll bar.

Comment: see this https://jsfiddle.net/jtboskp0/

Answer (score 0):

change css of first div

```
 <div style="width: 100%; border: solid 1px green;display: table;">
    <table id="tblMain">
```

see [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/z137yjfs/)

Comment: I already tried this but it should not exceed the upper div which is in green border color.